# My activity is sluggish, and has 6 ImageViews and CardViews. How do I compress or lower the image quality/size?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview, cardview

I have an activity on Android that is really sluggish and slow. It has 6 ImageViews, so I am guessing that they are causing it. How do I deal with them? Do I compress them, reduce their quality and how do I exactly achieve that? And are the CardViews causing any of the sluggishness? Should I compress the images from external tools like caesium and what size should I set them to? Also, are there any inbuilt functions to achieve that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#006064"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:onClick="goToChild"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="goToDash"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="181dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.02"
                        android:background="#B2FF59"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/dash2"
                        android:onClick="goToChild"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="DASHBOARD"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Open the Dashboard"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="goToSpy"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/routeOption"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.07"
                        android:background="#448AFF"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/docico" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="MY DOCUMENTS"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Save documents"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="goToPlanner"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/plannerOption"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                        android:layout_width="207dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.02"
                        android:background="#F44336"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/plannerico" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="PLANNER"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Set your Plans!"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="goToPlanner"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/taskOption"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="207dp"
                        android:layout_height="57dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.02"
                        android:background="#FFEB3B"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/tasks2" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="TASKS"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Tasks by Company"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:onClick="goToSummary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="goToSummary"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="181dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.02"
                        android:background="#FFEB3B"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/remico"
                        android:onClick="goToChild"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="REMARKS"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Company's Remarks"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="goToSettings"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/setting"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.07"
                        android:background="#B2FF59"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/meetico" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="MEETING MINUTES"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Meetings Summary"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw in your question and the information provided:

- If the images are resources (placed in drawable folder)  you should use adequate sizes for the screen size and resolution of the phone/tablet/etc.
- You can let Android compress the images but it would be better if you compress them using a program like photoshop,gimp or even Microsoft Office Photo Editor, even MS Word.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can reduce the "sluggishness".

- Make sure your images are available in different densities in density-specific folders. I like to use final android resizer (find the .jar online) to easily resize my images into the appropriate density folders.
- Run your images through a compression tool like ImageOptim or tinyPNG
- Use an image loading library like Glide or Picasso to load the image resources into your `ImageView`s
- Run your code through Android Lint and look under the performance issues for more clues

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) lib :

- add the dependency `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`
- then

  `ImageView imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
   Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.myimage).fit().
   centerCrop().into(imageView);`

> Be sure to use fit() to resize the image before loading into the
>   ImageView. Otherwise, you will consume extra memory, experience
>   sluggish scrolling, or encounter out of memory issues if you render a
>   lot of pictures

for more about Picasso see this [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Picasso-Library)

---

What causes the app to be sluggish is loading this large size into memory because you are using large image sizes, Picasso resizes and caches your images.